# My app crashes when add items to cart

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am doing a food ordering app and when I add to cart my app crashes I am using SQLite for the cart data

My logcat 
https://codeshare.io/5wOmyJ

My codes 
https://codeshare.io/aVPLK6
https://codeshare.io/aJ69pE

Comment: Your insert Query has the Syntax error, Post your Query code.

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: please post your cide of your databse method add to cart..

Comment: See these lines in your logcat? 'at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)' and 'at com.example.loy.queueeater.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:59)'. Start checking from here.

Comment: Please close insert query end bracket.  
INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('32','HAWAIIAN PIZZA','1','1000''0');

Comment: Actually, you are doing mistake in insert query logic, If you post logic of your addToCart code so we can help you resolve the issue.

Comment: I don’t understand?

Comment: @SantanuSur I don’t understand

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi close bracket?

Comment: @farhana query code ? As in the code for the SQLite database?

Comment: @user9411391 end off query you forgot close round bracket ')'.

Comment: @ user9411391           update your question with code

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi the code where I did the query https://codeshare.io/aVPLK6

Comment: @farhana my code where I did the query https://codeshare.io/aVPLK6

Comment: String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s''%s');",
                        order.getProductId(),
                        order.getProductName(),
                        order.getQuantity(),
                        order.getPrice(),
                        order.getDiscount());

Update this line.

Comment: You insert code has error. didn't close the bracket.

INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('32','HAWAIIAN PIZZA','1','1000''0');

Comment: @user9411391 you are doing mistake here '%s','%s','%s','%s''%s';", this is Syntax error

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi how do I end it ?

Comment: @AvinashVerma which line ?

Comment: @farhana how do I fix it?

Comment: @SantanuSur  https://codeshare.io/aVPLK6

Comment: @ScaryWombat https://codeshare.io/aVPLK6

Comment: have updated my code..just replace this with your `addToCart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this...

```
public void addToCart(Order order)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s''%s'));",
         order.getProductId(),
         order.getProductName(),
            order.getQuantity(),
            order.getPrice(),
            order.getDiscount());
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

You missed this closing bracket..

```
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s''%s'));" //
```

Comment: Ok I will try it now

Comment: update if it works

Comment: It doesn’t work still crashes when I add to cart m

Comment: show your logcat now..after trying this..

Comment: Nevermind sir I accidentally added a extra bracket thank you so much for your help

Comment: is it working now ? @user9411391

Comment: Yes it’s working perfectly now